# HQL pagination returns same result on different pages

Tags: java, spring, pagination, hql, jpa

We have the following query in the server:

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(
           "SELECT type, id, date, amount FROM Transaction ORDER BY type ASC");
```

The type field is not unique.

In order to implement pagination, we use the following code:

```
query.setFirstResult(currentPage * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize);
```

Meaning that if we want a page size of 10, and we have 15 results overall, the client sends `currentPage = 0, pageSize = 10` to display the first page, and `currentPage = 1, pageSize = 10` to display the second page.

It seems that in cases where the total results > page size we get the same results on different pages, and some result lines are not displayed at all (on any page).
Our guess is that this issue has to do with the fact that the sort field is not unique, because if we use the following query, it does not occur:

```
"SELECT type, id, date, amount FROM Transaction ORDER BY type ASC, id ASC"
```

Does anyone know why this happens? And how to solve it? (Other that just adding the id as a sort field as well).

Comment: Why don't you like having `id` in order by? You have to sort results by some unique id.

Comment: @AleksandrM why does the sort field need to be unique? It's not a problem when the pageSize >= total results size

Comment: *After a query has produced an output table (after the select list has been processed) it can optionally be sorted. If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified order.* - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-order.html.

Comment: Still not sure I understand why this affect the pagination? Even if the order of rows (within the sort field) is unspecified...

Comment: E.g. First query results 5,3,2,6,8,1; current page = 0; page size = 3 -> `5,3,2`. Second query results 6,1,2,5,8,3; current page = 1; page size = 3 -> `5,8,3`.

Comment: @Ayelet did you find any solution? I